# Reading and writing back yaml files with multi-line strings

Tags: yaml, multiline, pyyaml

I have to read a yaml file, modify it and write back using pyYAML. Every thing works fine except when there is multi-line string values in single quotes e.g. if input yaml file looks like

```
FOO:
  - Bar: '{"HELLO":
"WORLD"}'
```

then reading it as `data=yaml.load(open("foo.yaml"))` and writing it `yaml.dump(data, fref, default_flow_style=False)` generates something like

```
FOO:
- Bar: '{"HELLO": "WORLD"}'
```

i.e. without the extra line for `Bar` value. Strange thing is that if input file has something like

```
FOO:
- Bar: '{"HELLO":

    "WORLD"}'
```

i.e. one extra new line for `Bar` value then writing it back generates the correct number of new lines. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, but you probably should have read more of the YAML specification.

According to the (outdated) 1.1 spec that PyYAML implements, within
[single quoted scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id905860):

> In a multi-line single-quoted scalar, line breaks are subject to (flow) line folding, and any trailing white space is excluded from the content.

And [line-folding](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#line%20folding/):

> Line folding allows long lines to be broken for readability, while retaining the original semantics of a single long line. When folding is done, any line break ending an empty line is preserved. In addition, any specific line breaks are also preserved, even when ending a non-empty line.

This means that your first two examples are the same, as the
line-break is read as if there is a space.

The third example is different, because it *actually contains a newline after loading*, because "any line break ending an empty line is preserved".
In order to understand why that dumps back as it was loaded, you have to know that PyYAML doesn't 
maintain any information about the quoting (nor about the single newline in the first example), it 
just loads that scalar into a Python string. During dumping PyYAML evaluates how that string
can best be written and the options it considers (unless you try to force things using the `default_style` argument to `dump()`): plain style, single quoted style, double quoted style.

PyYAML will use plain style (without quotes) when possible, but since
the string starts with `{`, this leads to confusion (collision) with
that character's use as the start of a flow style mapping. So quoting
is necessary. Since there are also double quotes in the string, and
there are no characters that need backslash escaping the "cleanest"
representation that PyYAML can choose is single quoted style, and in
that style it needs to represent a line-break by including an emtpy
line withing the single quoted scalar.

I would personally prefer using a block style literal scalar to represent your last example:

```
FOO:
- Bar: |
  {"HELLO":
    "WORLD"}
```

but if you load, then dump that using PyYAML its readability would be lost.

Although worded differently in the YAML 1.2 specification (released almost 10 years ago) the line-folding works the same, so this would "work" in a similar way with a more up-to-date YAML loader/dumper. My package ruamel.yaml, for loading/dumping YAML 1.2 will properly maintain the block style if you set the attribute `preserve_quotes = True` on the `YAML()` instance, but it will still get rid of the newline in your first example. This could be implemented (as is shown by ruamel.yaml preserving appropriate newline positions in folded style block scalars), but nobody ever asked for that, probably because if people want that kind of control over wrapping they use a block style to start with.

Comment: thanks @Anthon for detail explanation. Yes I should have read the spec in more details.